# Update bootstrap-year-calendar without re-rendering the whole calendar?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Im using bootstrap calendar to both display requested dateranges (red underline) and request dateranges.

Currently, once the user has submitted his request, the calendar is updated via:

```
$('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(calendarDatasourceInput)
```

Everything runs smoothly, so theres no big issue here. However, I find it a bit annoying that the whole calendar re-renders when updating it via "setDataSource". 
So I wanted to ask here if anyone knows of a quick, easy solution to stop the widget from re-rendering the whole thing and instead just adding the new content to the existing display?

Comment: What do you mean you're using "bootstrap calendar"? Bootstrap doesn't ship with calendar widgets.

Comment: @pjones235 I mean this: http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Documentation/Events